# JQuery Append to SELECT (with multiple selection) wont work

Tags: jquery, select, append

I will first say the if I want to receive a form in my PHP file and read the select's multiple values that were sent, it works like this:

```
foreach ($_POST["selectaddedsubj"] as $selectedOption)
    echo $selectedOption."\n";
```

and that in order for that to work, the name and id of the select should be like that:

```
<select name="selectaddedsubj[]" id="selectaddedsubj[]" size="3" multiple="multiple">     
</select>
```

BUT, when I append values to it using jQuery, it will only work if I remove the [] from the name:

```
$("#selectaddedsubj").append($('<option>', {
    value: subjname,
    text: subjname,
    selected: 'selected'
}));
```

instead of `$("#selectaddedsubj[]").append` which wont work... :(

Can I receive multiple selection on my PHP page from a form's SELECT variable in a different way rather than naming it using "[]" on my form?

Comment: Only the name needs to be like that, the id is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is very much like the `id="foo.bar"` example at the top of the [jquery documentation page on selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). The CSS selector syntax requires quoting of identifiers containing special characters. The simple way of quoting them is with a backslash before each character:

```
$("#selectaddedsubj\\[\\]")
```

(Note: a double backslash in a javascript string literal results in a single backslash in the actual string, so the CSS parser sees `#selectaddedsubj\[\]` here.)

Another way, using the general attribute selector syntax instead of the magic `#` id syntax, allows you to avoid the backslashes by quoting the whole identifier:

```
$("[id='selectaddedsubj[]']")
```